# Spring-integration copy files and after copy read them and send data via http

Tags: java, spring-integration

I'm new with spring-integration and i want to do a few steps in every 5 sec:

1. Check directory is there are any file with extension .xml or .json.
2. If there are file with previous extension i want to copy a single file into other directory (if there are more files i want to copy them later it should working like loop: take first file do sth, go back, take second file etc.).
3. After copy a single file into directory i want to read this file and send data from file in String format into my rest app.
4. My rest app will process this data and give respond.
5. In last move i want to for example print given respond from http.

So to reach this i prepare some code like this:

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter id="filesIn" directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/input"
                              filename-regex="^.*\.(xml|json)$">
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000"/>
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:service-activator input-channel="filesIn"
                       output-channel="filesOut"
                       ref="handler"/>

<file:outbound-channel-adapter id="filesOut" directory="file:${java.io.tmpdir}/spring-integration-samples/output"
                               delete-source-files="true"/>
```

This code will check directory witch to find is there any files with extension .xml or .json every 5 second. 
My service-activator calling method:

```
public File handleFile(File input) {
    return input;
}
```

And after that file will be copied into other directory.

And the point is how after making copy file into new directory can i read this file and send data via http Post method.

Pls guys give me some example how to do this. I Find sth like this:

```
<int:gateway id="requestGateway"
             service-interface="com.integration.service.RequestService"
             default-request-channel="requestChannel" >
</int:gateway>


<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>

<int-http:outbound-gateway request-channel="requestChannel"
                           url="http://localhost:8080/import/v1/documents/go"
                           http-method="POST"
                           expected-response-type="org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity"                             >

</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

But to make execute this request i only can do this from java like this:

```
RequestService requestService = (RequestService)context.getBean("requestGateway");
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
obj.put("docID", "8");
obj.put("subject", "111111");
obj.put("content", "ssssss");
obj.put("type", "ddddd");
String doc = obj.toString();
ResponseEntity reply = requestService.echo(doc);
```

And here is my RequestServce interface:

```
public interface RequestService {
    ResponseEntity echo(String request);
}
```

I will be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you want to copy the file first; as long as you don't use any queue or executor channels, the whole flow will run on the poller thread and you won't get the next file until the first one has been processed.

If you must copy the file for some reason, add a second file inbound channel adapter to listen to the second directory; then a transformer (such as a file to string transformer); then the outbound http gateway.

Comment: I add a one more inbound channel adapter to check dist directory and after that i made a transform and other stuff. But no i'm trying to change this code into Java class config. How can i for example implement my copy  task? @GaryRussell

Comment: It's better to ask a new question, showing your current configuration and someone can help convert it to Java config.